# Shopping Basket Deal Optimization

Tags: integer-programming, combinatorial-optimization

I am looking for guidance on a solution to the problem of picking the best special offers that can be applied to a given basket of items.

In the system, a special offer has N collections of qualifying items, to satisfy the offer an item from the basket must match an item from each of the collections. If a special offer is satisfied then a type of discount is applied. Each product in a basket can only be used once to qualify a special offer.

Some deals and some products could look like this

```
// deals
{
  Id: 1,
  Name: "Bogof 1",
  Items: [
    [1,2,3], // Item ID's in this group
    [1,2],
    [1]
  ],
  Price: 2.6
},

{
  Id: 2,
  Name: "Bogof 2",
  Items: [
    [1,2], // Item ID's in this group
    [1,2],
    [1,2]
  ],
  Price: 2.5
},

{
  Id: 3
  Name: "Buy 5 get 1 Free",
  Items: [
    [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20],
    [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20],
    [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20],
    [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20],
    [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20],
  ],
  Price: 4
}

// Products

[{
  Id: 1,
  Price: 1,
},{
  Id: 2,
  Price: 1.2,
},{
  Id: 3,
  Price: 1.5,
},
]
```

I have simplified the offers here with an absolute price, but there could be something more dynamic like cheapest free.

If I have the basket

`[1,2,3] // Item ID's`

and I was to naively iterate the item groups in the deal, **1** would match the first row (of deal 1) and **2** would match the second, but **3** would not match the third row, which means really I would need to generate all the permutations and iterate those instead, however, now imagine an offer with 50 items, the same 50 in each group, but 10 groups, if I was to apply that same logic to the 50*10 scenario that is 50<sup>10</sup> permutations.

Now if I have the basket

`[1,1,1,2,3]`

The code also needs to be able to pick the optimal offer which would give the best discount, which in this case would be offer 1, not 2, because offer 1 offers the largest discount of the items.

From reading about similar problems it seems like Integer programming might offer a solution, but I am looking at the Knapsack or Bin packing vs assignment and trying to figure out where to start. Should I have a binary variable for each item in a basket multiplied by each meal deal item collection, or can I just have variables for the meal deals and their item collections and set constraints using the products? I am also not sure which Solver would be best. I am using C# and have been having a play with Google Or Tools.

Maybe there is another way to reduce the problem.

Comment: You said "picking the best special offers" (plural). Does this mean that a single basket of items can collect on every offer for which it qualifies? Alternatively, can you collect multiple offers provided that no item in the basket is used to earn more than one offer?

Comment: I have edited the question to clarify

Comment: Just to be clear, your example basket $[1,1,1,2,3]$ would cost 5.7 without any discounts, and with offer 1 would cost 4.6 (2.6 for the offer, which would match one unit each of items 1, 2 and 3 plus 2 for the remaining two units of item 1 at list price)?